# Matrix Exponential and Conjugation of Jordan Normal Form and Real Normal Form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, change-of-basis, matrix-exponential

Given a diagonalizable matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{N \times N}}$, we can decompose $A$ in following terms:

1. $A = V \Lambda_{C} V^{-1}$ where $V, \Lambda_{C} \in \mathbb{C^{N \times N}}$
2. $A = Q \Lambda_{R} Q^{-1}$ where $Q, \Lambda_{R} \in \mathbb{R^{N \times N}}$

In a matrix form, we can see the following relationship in a simplist case:

$
\Lambda_{C} = \begin{pmatrix}
a + bi & 0 \\
0 & a - bi
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\Lambda_{R} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
P \Lambda_{R} P^{-1} = \Lambda_{C} \quad (P = V^{-1}Q)
$

Now, the question arises when we take a matrix exponential.

$exp(\Lambda_C) = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{a + bi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{a - bi}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
e^a (cos(b) + isin(b)) & 0 \\
0 & e^a (cos(b) - isin(b))
\end{pmatrix}
$

Again, we can change the basis of this matrix to make it real form. Let's say we have another matrix $K \in \mathbb{C}$:

$
Kexp(\Lambda_C)K^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
e^a cos(b) & e^a sin(b) \\
-e^a sin(b) & e^a cos(b))
\end{pmatrix} = \Lambda
$

Here, I am not sure on following questions:

1. Is $exp(\Lambda_{R}) = \Lambda$?
2. Related question. Is $K = P = V^{-1}Q$?

Core concept of the question is finding a conjugate matrix that changes Jordan Normal Form to Real Normal Form.

Comment: Technically $K$ is not unique but there is a canonical choice to go from your complex form to your real form. You are not guaranteed that $K=P=V^{-1}Q$ but this choice works. Also Yes for the first question if the process of "realification" is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. “Not guaranteed” but “this choice works” mean, if I take a canonical choice, they will be same? Could you kindly guide me to prove this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Also my bad, $K$ should be equal to $P^{-1}$

Comment: Normally $K = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i &1 \end{pmatrix}$ or it’s conjugate should work